# $\mathbb{Z}^n/R$ where $R$ is subgroup generated by rows of $n\times n$ integer matrix $M$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, smith-normal-form

Let $R$ be the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ generated by the rows of integer matrix $M$.

I want to show that $det M=0$ implies $\mathbb{Z}^n/R$ is infinite, and also that $det M\neq 0$ implies $|\mathbb{Z}^n/R|=|det M|$.

I know I must use the Smith normal form in some way, as that is what we have been studying.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2648447/mathrmcard-mathbbzn-m-mathbbzn-detm, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/245733/index-of-a-sublattice-in-a-lattice-and-a-homomorphism-between-them